# Switching Frames In PyQt4

Tags: python, pyqt4

I would like to know how I would go about doing the following in PyQt4:

```
import tkinter as tk

LARGE_FONT= ("Verdana", 12)

class SeaofBTCapp(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        container = tk.Frame(self)

        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand = True)

        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}

        for F in (StartPage, PageOne):

            frame = F(container, self)

            self.frames[F] = frame

            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame(StartPage)

    def show_frame(self, cont):

        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()


class StartPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Home", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10,padx=10) 
        btn = tk.Button(self, text="Page One", command= lambda: controller.show_frame(PageOne))
        btn.pack()

class PageOne(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Page One", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)
        btn = tk.Button(self, text="Home", command= lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))
        btn.pack()


app = SeaofBTCapp()
app.mainloop()
```

I am going to have multiple pages and would like to have it easily defined. I am still very new to python coding and I'm still learning how PyQt4 works but my project will have atleast 4 pages that I need to switch between and I don't want the code to be too long by defining the same thing on every page's class. All help will be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [QStackedWidget](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstackedwidget.html).

From the docs:

> The QStackedWidget class provides a stack of widgets where only one widget is visible at a time.

Depending on what you are doing exactly, [QWizard](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwizard.html) may be suited even better.

Both also exist for Qt4, but you should use Qt5 if you can.